# como enlazar varias clases

Tags: c++, poo, clase, object, compilar

He creado una clase base llamada `forma.h`, en la el metodo `area` es **abstracto** porque lo voy a definir de manera diferente para cada figura que haga

```
#ifndef _FORMA_
#define _FORMA_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Forma{
    protected:
        int ancho;
        int alto;
    public:
        Forma(int x, int y);
        virtual int area() = 0;
};

#endif
```

Consecuente a esto, he creado su correspondiente `forma.cc`de la siguiente manera:

```
#include "forma.h"
Forma::Forma(int x, int y){
    ancho = x;
    alto = y;
}
```

Luego he querido crear una rectángulo, para ello he escrito este `rectangulo.h`:

```
#ifndef _RECTANGULO_
#define _RECTANGULO_
#include "forma.h"

class Rectangulo: public Forma{
    public:
        Rectangulo(int x, int y);
        int area();
};

#endif
```

y el siguiente `rectangulo.cc`:

```
#include "rectangulo.h"

Rectangulo::Rectangulo(int x, int y) : Forma(x, y){

}

int Rectangulo::area(){
    return ancho*alto;
}
```

para unirlo todo he creado este `mainForma.cc`:

```
#include "forma.h"
#include "rectangulo.h"

int main(){
    Rectangulo re(2, 3);
    cout << "AREA: " << re.area() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

El problema viene cuando lo ejecuto todo para que me de el area del rectangulo. Al compilarlo con `g++ -g -o mainForma mainForma.cc` saltan todos estos errores:

```
/tmp/ccyR0V55.o: En la función `main':
/home/Escritorio/prep/mainForma.cc:5: referencia a `Rectangulo::Rectangulo(int, int)' sin definir
/home/Escritorio/prep/mainForma.cc:6: referencia a `Rectangulo::area()' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

¿¿Cual es el fallo??

Comment: El fallo es este: _no matching function for call to ‘Rectangulo::Rectangulo(int, int)’_ Te falta el constructor en la clase `Rectangulo`.

Comment: @SuperG280 lo he añadido pero creo que me sigue faltando algo porque me sigue saliendo otro error

Comment: Solo estás compilando mainForma.cc, te faltaría compilar rectangulo.cc y linkar todo

Comment: Es un buena idea definir un destructor virtual para `Forma`. Otra buena idea es usar especificador `override` para `Rectangulo::area` [ver](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esos errores los está generando el enlazador y el problema es que no estás incluyendo los archivos `forma.cc` ni `rectangulo.cc`.

`g++ -g -o` sirve para compilar y enlazar en una única pasada, pero cuando tienes varios archivos puede ser problemático.

Lo que tienes que hacer es, por un lado, compilar los diferentes fuentes:

```
g++ -g -c forma.cc
g++ -g -c rectangulo.cc
g++ -g -c mainForma.cc
```

La opción `-c` indica a g++ que únicamente debe generar código objeto, evitando así que intente enlazar el código en este paso

Y, finalmente, enlazar los tres archivos de código objeto para componer el binario final

```
g++ -g -o mainForma forma.o rectangulo.o mainForma.o
```

Comment: pero `area` no es un `.cc`, es una funcion del codigo... ¿lo compilo como has dicho igualemente? @eferion

Comment: @sonlas10 perdona, fue una errata

Comment: Ahora todo enlaza correctamente pero no imprime nada. Sabes por que podría ser??

Comment: @sonlas10 Eso no es que se quede parado... es el prompt... ya ha terminado de enlazar y está a la espera de que metas la siguiente instrucción... que debería ser ejecutar el programa...

Comment: Cierto, he tenido un lapsus

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta :)

Comment: También se puede compilar todo sin generar ficheros objeto intermedios, aunque para proyectos grandes es recomendable hacerlo, porque acorta tiempos de compilación si solo se modifica una pequeña parte del programa. Se haría con el comando `g++ -g -o mainForma mainForma.cc forma.cc rectangulo.cc`.

Comment: @EequiisVásquez realmente lo suyo sería utilizar un Makefile o compilar usando cmake o alguna otra alternativa... escribir comandos a pelo no suele ser la tónica habitual

Comment: Cierto. Conforme se avanza hacia proyectos más grandes suele ser el paso natural ir hacia una compilación automatizada.